# Can't add second app to Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

Some time ago I added my android app to Fabric Crashlytics and it works fine. Now I want to add the second app but fabric creates for me the same key as for the first application. what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Crashlytics's key belong to an 'Organization', which can have multiple apps.

By using the same key on a different app, the app will be added to the same Organization.

If you want different key, make a new Organization from the settings page in the console.

Fabric will create the same key because a single key can have multiple apps and this happened because key belongs to organization not to the app.

Comment: but my app crash on       Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics()); in BaseApp.class and logcat whrites to sign up in fabric